# Unexpected syntax error in controller file (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel-5

The error I got is this:

> FatalErrorException in searchController.php line 148:
>   syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)

Here is my code:

```
    if($criteria == 'courses'){

    //return redirect()->back();    <-- if I uncomment this code and remove the code from "$result" all the way down to the second "return view" code, I don't get an error.
    $result=schools::whereRaw("MATCH(undergradcourses,postgradcourses) AGAINST('$searchItem')")->where('status','')->get();

    if(count($result)>0){

    $count=count($result);

    return view('schools', array('result' => $result))->with(array('searchItem'=>$searchItem,'criteria'=>$criteria,'count'=>$count))->with('searchItem',$searchItem);   

    }

    else{

        return view('schools')->with(array('msg'=>'Oops, No result found','count'=>'0','searchItem'=>$searchItem,'criteria'=>$criteria));

    }

    }



    //sort search

    public function sortsearch(Request $request){ <-- this is line 148
```

If you can see from the comments I made above, if I uncommented `return redirect()->back();` and removed the rest of the code from `$result` to the `else` code, no error displays and page works fine.

I copied this code from the code above it (it focuses on requests that deal with schools) which works fine:

```
    public function postsearch(Request $request){

    $searchItem=$request['searchItem'];

    $criteria=$request['criteria'];

    if($criteria == 'schools'){

    $result=schools::whereRaw("MATCH(name,describtion) AGAINST('$searchItem')")->where('status','')->get();

    if(count($result)>0){

    $count=count($result);

    return view('schools', array('result' => $result))->with(array('searchItem'=>$searchItem,'criteria'=>$criteria,'count'=>$count))->with('searchItem',$searchItem);   

    }

    else{

        return view('schools')->with(array('msg'=>'Oops, No result found','count'=>'0','searchItem'=>$searchItem,'criteria'=>$criteria));

    }

    }
```

Comment: Did you close previous function tag?

Comment: You have an "if" condition that is not closed properly, missing a curly brace OR you're missing a curly brace to close the function. Try using an IDE, it will highlight minor errors such as these.

Comment: Or try al least __correct__ indentation for nested structures.

Comment: @user1453870 I am.  Using Sublime Text 3.

Comment: @Thomas In sublime, you can actually see the pair or brackets/curly braces, place your cursor just before a closing bracket/brace, and you'll see the opening one being highlighted also (highlight in this case is the braces being underlined)

Comment: The problem was I was missing a bracket.  The else statement had its own bracket.  Needed an additional bracket to close out the function.  Just needed additional time (and input from the internet) to figure it out.